# rspec-html-matchers finds html and body tags in HTML without them

Tags: html, ruby, rspec, matcher

I have a very simple directory with an `index.html` file that I'm testing with [rspec-html-matchers](https://github.com/kucaahbe/rspec-html-matchers).

I've configured it in `spec_helper.rb` like so:

```
require "rspec-html-matchers"

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include RSpecHtmlMatchers

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
end
```

The tests are mostly working as expected, but now I'm testing for the presence of `<html>` and `<body>` tags and getting (what I think is) an incorrect result.

### Example

Here's a really simple test that I think should fail:

```
describe "index" do
  it "does something weird" do
    expect("<h1>just a header</h1>").to have_tag('html')
  end
end
```

The string clearly does *not* contain an `<html>` tag, so it should fail.

This test:

- also unexpectedly passes if I use `have_tag('body')`
- fails, as I expect, if I use `have_tag('h2')`
- fails, as I expect, if I use `have_tag('LOLBBQ')`

What am I missing? How can I test for the presence of correctly implemented `<html>` and `<body>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[rspec-html-matchers' `have_tag` parses the document with Nokogiri's HTML parser](https://github.com/kucaahbe/rspec-html-matchers/blob/master/lib/rspec-html-matchers.rb#L108), which adds the missing tags that are required by the HTML standard. You can see this in irb:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'nokogiri'
irb(main):002:0> Nokogiri::HTML '<p>Hi</p>'
=> #<Nokogiri::HTML::Document:0x3fedb1935a60 name="document" children=[
     #<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x3fedb19353f8 name="html">,
     #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fedb1934f84 name="html" children=[
       #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fedb1934a70 name="body" children=[
         #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fedb1934804 name="p" children=[
           #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fedb19344bc "Hi">]>]>]>]>
```

Capybara's `have_selector` matcher also uses `Nokogiri::HTML` and has the same effect.

If your HTML is XHTML, you can test for `html` and `body` tags with Nokogiri's XML parser in strict mode:

```
it "has html and body tags" do
  string = "<html><body><p>Hi</p></body></html>"
  # The following raises an error if the string contains unbalanced tags
  xml = Nokogiri::XML(string) { |config| config.options = Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::STRICT }
  htmls = xml.children.select { |child| child.name == 'html' }
  expect(htmls.length).to eq(1)
  bodys = htmls.first.children.select { |child| child.name == 'body' }
  expect(bodys.length).to eq(1)
end
```